# Javascript canvas drawLineDash to only one line

Tags: javascript

On my application I have to draw separate lines. One line solid and one line dashed. I am using the [CanvasRenderingContext2D](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D). My problem is how can I draw one dotted line and one solid line using the same context. What I have tried is:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.setLineDash([2, 2])
ctx.moveTo(50, 50);   // Begin first sub-path
ctx.lineTo(200, 50);
ctx.moveTo(50, 90);   // Begin second sub-path
ctx.lineTo(280, 120);
ctx.stroke();
```

But it draws lines as dotted. It makes sense why, because I am using the same context for both lines but I need to use the same context in my app. I just gave a minimal example. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In a canvas I would recommend to use some sort of prototype to represent a point in your coordinate system. Then you can simply pass the points to your `drawLine` function and pass an additional `style`.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function Point(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

function drawLine(from, to, style=[]) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.setLineDash(style)
  ctx.moveTo(from.x, from.y);
  ctx.lineTo(to.x, to.y);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
}

drawLine(new Point(50, 50), new Point(200, 50)); // solid line
drawLine(new Point(50, 90), new Point(280, 120), [2,2]); // dashed line
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```